# Is it possible to have a mexopts.bat that links both 32 AND 64bit compilers?

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, mex

I have Matlab 2010b and Microsoft VS2010.

For project related reasons I need to use alternatively the 32 and 64 bit version of Matlab.

I currently have two `mexopts.bat` files that I rename depending on the Matlab version I use to correctly link to the relevant compiler.

Is there a way to have a single file with links to both compilers and have Matlab automatically pick up the relevant one?

Comment: You can specify a mexopts file via the mex command line.  What about writing a small wrapper script for mex which detects the architecture and chooses the correct opts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401351/peter)'s comment, I investigated the command line options.

An automatic way of doing what I need is:

```
version = mexext;

if (version(5) == '3') % this is 32bit

    % include 32bit version code

elseif (version(5) == '6') % this is 64bit

    % include 64bit version code

else

    % deal with problems (should never occour)

end
```

the `mex` command(s) will have to include the option `-f $full_path_to_correct_mexopts.bat`